# 1С-Битрикс и серверные заголовки

Tags: seo, php, cms, битрикс

Может быть, вопрос немного ламерский, но все же задам. Кто что знает по этому поводу: корректно ли CMS 1С-Битрикс передает заголовки (типа Last-Modified, Expires и т.д.)? Вопрос в принципе относится к SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Да нормально относится, в шаблоне пропиши

```
<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("keywords")?>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("description")?>
```

между `<head>`, и в описание страницы заноси свои ключевики.

Answer (score 1):

Заголовок Last-Modified bitrix "из коробки" не передает. Это одна из "SEO-проблем" битрикса. Обсуждение этого вопроса ведется на форуме разработчиков - http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic8100/

Вот код который использую я (работает и в случае с NGINX). Что бы не модифицировать ядро этот участок кода вставляете в /bitrix/admin/php_interface/init.php.

```
<?
AddEventHandler('main', 'OnEpilog', array('CBDPEpilogHooks', 'CheckIfModifiedSince'));
class CBDPEpilogHooks
{
   function CheckIfModifiedSince()
   {
      GLOBAL $lastModified;
      if (!$lastModified) $lastModified=time()-1000;
      if ($lastModified)
      {
         header("Cache-Control: public");
         header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $lastModified).' GMT');

         if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) >= $lastModified) {
             header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified'); exit();
         }          
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Глобальная переменная $lastModified определяет время изменения страницы.

Для страницы детального просмотра элемента определить ее можно так:

1) в result_modifier.php шаблона компонента детального просмотра сохраняем TIMESTAMP_X в кеше компонента:

```
$cp = $this->__component; // объект компонента
if (is_object($cp))
   $cp->SetResultCacheKeys(array('TIMESTAMP_X'));
```

2) в component_epilog.php того же шаблона определяем переменную $lastModified:

```
GLOBAL $lastModified;
if (!$lastModified)
   $lastModified = MakeTimeStamp($arResult['TIMESTAMP_X']);
else
   $lastModified = max($lastModified, MakeTimeStamp($arResult['TIMESTAMP_X']));
```

Корректно проверить поле Last-Modified можно здесь: http://www.bertal.ru/index.php?ex=1

Comment: Не подскажите куда поместить файлы result_modifier.php и component_epilog.php? В какую папку?